# Why the same git script is producing different hashes?

Tags: git, hash

I'm writing a script to serve as an example of Git usage. However, every time I run it, a different set of hashes are produced, even if the commit message, author, date, parent and contents are the same:

```
rm -rf /tmp/git-teste
git init /tmp/git-teste
cd /tmp/git-teste
echo 'zero' > master.txt
git add .
git commit -am zero --date '2013-05-28 16:40:00' --author 'andre <teste@teste.com>'
```

Shouldn't the hash has been always the same? What should I change to assure this happen?

Comment: Are you deleting `/tmp/git-teste` first?

Comment: `--date` overrides the *author date*.  You have a different *committer date* at every commit.

Answer (score 6):

A Git commit has two dates: an author date, which you set with `commit --date`, and a commit date. Both are used to compute the SHA1. The commit date can be set using the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable, see `git help commit-tree`.

Answer (score 2):

larsmans is correct about the commit date being different. Try this for your last line:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='2013-05-28 16:40:00' GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE git commit -am zero --author 'andre <teste@teste.com>'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like even if you set `author` there is a `committer` field set automatically.

Note that you can find out the difference by looking at the object tree by hand, looking up a different object, and using `git cat-file -p A1234` where `A1234` is the first 5 characters of the hash (or however many to guarantee uniqueness)

For instance I found the following:

```
tree 552ae24725bacabda77c585b56b260ccac74c003
author andre <teste@teste.com> 1369784400 -0700
committer Username <username@email.com> 1369773739 -0700

zero
```